# HTML form input is not grabbed by PHP script

Tags: php, html

When I click on the submit button after filling name and mail id columns , data entered in those fields is not shown in php page.

HTML code :-

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="data.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP code :-

```
Welcome <?php echo $_REQUEST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

Comment: what are you getting?? and what is the extension of your files??

Comment: print the post variable at the starting of the .php page using `print_r($_POST)` and let us know result.

Comment: I just ran it on my own system (cutpaste from your question), and it appears to work. What output are you seeing?

Comment: Are you sure you are running this through PHP and that your server is actually set up to process PHP files? If you view the source on the second page, do you see `<?php echo $_REQUEST["name"]; ?>` in the HTML?

Comment: I am using XAMPP server V 3.2.1 and activated APACHE module.

Comment: I get the following printed on PHP page after clicking on submit  and name and mail id entered is not displayed    "Welcome 
Your email address is:"

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this;

### HTML

```
    <body>
        <form action="data.php" method="post">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

### PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"])){
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        if(!empty($name) && !empty($email){
            echo "Your name is $name with the email : $email";
        } else {
            echo "Name or Email is not set";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs an explanation. As it stands, it's not clear that it fixes whatever problem OP is actually having.

Comment: It is same as before and its result is also same.